# Fundamental solution for ODE with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

It is known via the Malgrange-Ehrenpreis theorem that a PDE with constant coefficients has a fundamental solution [1]. However, the situation seems more obscure for PDE with non-constant coefficients. It seems that some related solution still exist on a case-by-case basis, see for instance [2]. I am interested in the fundamental solution to the following ODE (without boundary conditions):
$$
(1+ \alpha x) u_{xx} + \alpha u_{x} + (\omega^2/\alpha^2) u = 0
$$
In other words, I am interested in the function $u^\ast(x,\xi)$ solution to
$$(1+\alpha x)u^\ast_{xx}(x,\xi)+\alpha u^\ast_x(x,\xi)+(\omega^2/\alpha^2)u^\ast(x,\xi)=\delta(x-\xi)$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution.

At the moment, I am not able to find its fundamental solution if it exists.

---

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution 
[2] [Green's function for Bessel ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091034/greens-function-for-bessel-ode)

Comment: Wolfram finds $c_1J_0(2a\sqrt{x})+c_2Y_0(2a\sqrt{x})$, the Bessel functions of first and second kind.

Comment: @K.defaoite This seems to be the homogeneous solution? Not the fundamental solution?

Comment: @pluton I'm not sure what you mean. Usually the "fundamental solutions" just another name for the homogeneous solutions.

Comment: @K.defaoite yes but in the framework of Boundary Element Method,it has another meaning I think

Comment: @K.defaoite Thank you for your info. I have updated the question. The fundamental solution should be the solution to the equation above.